# How do you language options in your kivy app

Tags: android, python-3.x, language-features

I'm trying to create an app using kivy and would like to add a language option.

I was wondering whether that means that every word the app displays in English has to be manually translated. But that would mean that the code would be twice as long and that seem inefficient.

Or I could create a file for each language and that file will contain all the words in that will be displayed. For example.

```
import languages
print(languages.pt(greet))
```

And the output would be something like

```
"Olá. Tudo bem!"
```

Or is there another way?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor

Comment: This is probably my fault for not specifying this but I'm using python. How can it be done in python?

Answer (score -1):

You can visit android developers [website](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) for more information.

You can support another language in your app by just following these steps:

1. in **res -> values** open **strings.xml** file.
2. at top right corner you can see **Open editor**. Click on it
3. in the new window at the top left corner, click **Add locale** icon
4. choose any language you want to support (in this case find and choose **English (EN)**).
5. you can now see that this locale is added in your **values** file.

Now you are done with adding another language. Just remember if you add any text in your `default strings.xml`, add it's equal in `strings.xml (EN)` file too.

So till now, you have texts for both languages you support. But how to use `English` language?

In your activity add the following code inside of `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setLocale("en");

        ...
}

private void setLocale(String locale) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(new Locale(locale.toLowerCase()));
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```